# Auto-validate paper-input within dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm dynamically creating some `required` & `auto-validate`-d `<paper-input>` elements within a `<template is="dom-repeat">`.

It seems like auto-validation doesn't take place when the element is dom-repeated. It only happens when the element is blurred.

An example:

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">

<dom-module id="x-example">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      max-width: 320px;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">
      <paper-input label="this input requires some text" value="{{item::input}}" required auto-validate error-message="needs some text!"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </template>
<script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    "use strict";

    Polymer({

      is: "x-example",
      properties: {
       data: {
          type: Array,
          value: [
           "Hello World!",
            null,
            "Hello Globe!"
          ]
        }
      }

    });
  });
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-example></x-example>
```

- The 2nd `<paper-input>` has `null` value so I'm expecting this to have it's error message displayed  when it was *dom-repeated, **not** only after the user has focused and then blurred out of it.*
- Is there any straightforward way to run the auto-validation when the elements are dom-repeated, i.e when the element is instantiated/registered (for lack of a better word) ?

---

**Notes:**

- I'm aware that I can manually call `validate()` on the elements but I'm looking for a more lightweight/declarative way.
- Right now I've hacked up a *Behavior* that:

  - Observes the `splices` of the `dom-repeat` feed `data`
  - When `data` is changed, it manually calls `validate()` on all DOM elements with a `[required]` attribute.

Again, I'm looking for something more lightweight as I believe auto-validation should take place automatically, without me writing additional code for it.

Comment: this seems to be by design from the Polymer team, see https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/issues/381